# Why are my embedded youtube videos playing from the beginning rather than the specified timestamp?

Tags: discussion

I intend to self-answer this question to share what I just learned.

I used several Youtube videos in an answer recently. For some of them, I wanted to cue the video to start at a certain point. In Youtube, I clicked "Share" below the video, and then checked the "Start at X:XX" box to add a timestamp to the URL:

[image]

If I paste this URL on its own line within my answer, the video is not just linked but embedded. But, after submitting my answer and trying it out, the video played from the beginning.

Answer (score 8):

Googling this behavior turns up many complaints across the web. Some fix it by choosing the "embed" option and getting an actual iframe. But I found an easier solution: At Youtube, while the video is playing, right-click on it and you get a menu that includes "Copy video URL at current time." This generates a simple URL like the "share" function, but different (I suspect it removes some meta data like the fact that it's you who shared it? or placement within a playlist? not sure), and *it works* within the SE answer.

[image]

Comment: That is helpful - I was wondering about this, but assumed some folks had messed up when copying the URL.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! It seems to me that the only difference is removing `feature=shared&` from the link, so one can do it easily manually as well.